# iwconfig operation not permitted?

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

I'm running the following command:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan1 essid "wifi network"
```

I keep getting back:

```
SET failed on device wlan1 ; Operation not permitted.
```

On other computers there is no problem.

I'm wondering if I need to change the mode first? How can I go about debugging this issue?

Comment: What is your distro and what version?

Comment: @arochester Ubuntu 14.04 on an embedded device

Comment: What mode/type is that interface (`iw wlan1 show`)?

Comment: @dirkt when I use that command I get a long message about how to use `iw` as if it is the wrong syntax. https://pastebin.com/AGEq6pw4

Comment: @dirkt on my laptop I can do `iw <interface> info` for devices shown on `ifconfig` but on the embedded device I get back `command failed: No such device (-19)`

Comment: Yes, I meant `iw wlan1 info`, sorry. If you get "no such device", please do `iw dev` instead, and edit question with output.

Comment: @dirkt strange `iw dev` returns nothing, no error, no output. Tried sudo and non-sudo.

Comment: Guess: Something about your driver and/or utility setup is broken. Try to upgrade to the newest kernel and newest version of `iw` possible for you, including any library dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to be able to fix the problem by putting the interface in `ad-hoc` mode:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode ad-hoc
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
sudo iwconfig wlan1 essid "wifi network"
```

*Update: I tried the same process with `auto`, and `managed` which also worked. The mode `master` did not work.*

Comment: But then the interface is in ad-hoc mode, and unless you have lots of other devices in ad-hoc mode and want to make a mesh, that's probably not the mode you want ...